# Exiting a while loop at EOF using scanf in C

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, eof

I'm writing a few very small programs for my introductory C course. One of them requires me to read in double values, one number per line, and then print out basic statistics after EOF. Here is my the segment of my code that is giving me issues:

```
double sample[1000000];
int result;
double number; 
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
double sum = 0;
double harmosum = 0;
result = scanf(" %lf \n", &number); 
double min = number;
double max = number; 

while(result != EOF){

    sample[i] = number;
    if(number < min){
        min = number;
    }
    if(number > max){
        max = number;
    }
    sum += number;
    if(number != 0){
        harmosum += (1 / number);
        count++;
    }
    i++;
    result = scanf(" %lf \n", &number);  
}
```

After this I calculate and print some statistics based on the numbers.

My issue is, I am never making it out of the loop that scans each line. Why is this? When I press the EOF key on windows (CTRL-Z?) the console says:

^Z
Suspended

and that is it. Nothing else in the program runs. I have tried taking input from a text file but the end of the file is not detected there either. How should I fix this loop? Note I am only able to use basic scanf() no variation of the function. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the `<ctrl> + <D>` combination that sends `EOF`?

Comment: @H2CO3 It's `CTRL + Z` look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

Comment: Maybe you are using some linux emulation software like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com)? On linux, pressing that key combination suspends your program.

Comment: I am using Putty to emulate a linux shell, sorry I should have mentioned that. ctrl d doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: 2nd problem.  Be sure to check for `result` for values of 0 (maybe letters were entered) as well as the expected 1 when a good number is entered.

Comment: Does your problem even complie as a C program? I am not sure. You have variable declaration after `result = scanf(" %lf \n", &number);`

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie And? C allows mixed declarations and statements for more than a decade.

Comment: @DanielFischer just compiled the code in VS2010 it doesn't work. Have to change places so that I don't get a bunch of random error.

Comment: Change format from `" %lf \n"` to `" %lf\n"`.  (drop the 2nd space).  For me, the ^Z then works.

Comment: @spinsawsquad Remove the trailing whitespace from the `scanf` format. `result = scanf("%lf", &number);` is perfectly fine, and doesn't wait for anything non-whitespace after scanning the number.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie That's because Microsoft's compiler only accepts C90 (close enough). It hasn't kept up with the language.

Comment: @chux the program requirements state that input is guaranteed to be a valid number and nothing else, but we need to account for whitespace before or after and empty lines. Also, removing the whitespace from the scanf doesn't fix anything for me. Any other ideas? Thanks for the input so far guys!

Comment: Change format to `"%lf"`,  No spaces.  %lf by it self will consume optional leading whitespace - including the `\n` from the previous entry.  ^Z should then work too.

Comment: @spinsawsquad The `%lf` conversion skips initial whitespace, so the space before that does exactly nothing. The whitespace after the `%lf` makes `scanf` not return before it found the next non-whitespace character after the number has been scanned (or the end of input has been detected). You should probably check `while(scanf("%lf", &number) == 1)`, the return value is the number of successful conversions, and `EOF` is only returned if a read error occurs, or the end of input/a matching failure occurs before the first successful conversion.

Comment: Also, a Ctrl-D at the very start of a line closes `stdin`, and elsewhere only sends the input typed so far. To close `stdin`, you may need to type Ctrl-D twice.

Comment: @chux chaning the format to "%f" didn't fix it unfortunately. I entered a number, hit enter, entered another number, hit enter, then hit ctrl-z and it said ^Z Suspended and the rest of the program didn't execute.

Comment: @DanielFischer so should i check that it is equal to 1 and != EOF?

Comment: Check just that the conversion succeeded, if not, exit the loop. No need to fuss with `EOF` and closing `stdin`.

Comment: You mentioned changing to `"%f"`.  It should be `"%lf"`.  (`l` missing)

Comment: Yeah that was one of the first things I tried before this, I get the same results as when I'm checking for just != EOF. If i hit ctrl z i get ^Z Suspended. If i enter a character or string, i get Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @chux sorry I meant to type "%lf", I didn't set it to "%f"

Comment: Does ^Z work if it is the _first_ entry?

Comment: It does not. I get the same output: ^Z Suspended. ctrl z just stops input correct? It doesn't terminate the program. This is getting frustrating because it's so simple but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Yes frustrating.  Try `char ch; result = scanf("%lf%c", &number, &ch);`  This will consume the _Enter_ key into `ch`.  Then when scanf comes around again, it will not have a danging whitespace to read, then the ^Z should cause EOF.  Sadly I am getting inconsistent results....

Comment: Hmm, now if I enter a number I get another Segmentation fault (core dumped) also, ^Z doesnt cause EOF if used as first input

Comment: Replacing both `scanf()`?

Comment: yes both are     result = scanf("%lf%c", &number, &ch);

Comment: I suspect something in your scanf() line is causing the seg fault.  Please post.  I'll post my best answer, its working for me, maybe the is _something_ interesting about your systems console I/O that is evading us?

Comment: I think you want `while (result == 1)`, don't you?  That way any parsing error also bails out.  Otherwise, I _think_ `scanf()` will leave the read pointer pointing at whatever it can't read and then keep on returning 0 over and over.

Comment: It's also tempting to point out that if you use `Ctrl+C` it won't matter if it's DOS or Unix, and the loop will terminate.

Comment: @sh1 unfortunately, using while(result == 1) was one of the first alternatives I tried and it has had no effect on the results. Also, I have tried Ctrl+C and it just terminates the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is a simplification of your I/O issues.

`" %lf "` supplies 3 scanf() format directives: 1) white-space 2) double specifier, 3) white-space.

The first white-space directive is not needed as the `%lf` allows for optional leading whitespace.  The 2nd white-space directive causes problems as it consumes the *Enter key*, waiting for additional input.

```
"%lf" supplies 1 scanf() format directives: double specifier
```

This consumes optional leading white-space, including any previous \n, then scans for and hopefully decodes a double.  A `\n` (*Enter key*) following the number is left in the input buffer for the next input (the next scanf()).

---

Now as to **why your control Z is failing**.  It appears your console is consuming the ^Z and performing a "suspend job".  My console, instead of giving the ^Z to the program, closes the stdin input.  In essence putting an EOF in stdin.

So you need to either:
1) Find your console's mechanism for closing the stdin - others have suggested ^D.
2) Use an alternative to exit your loop.  I suggest `result != 1` which readily occurs when non-numeric input is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int result;
  double x = 0.0;
  do {
    // result = scanf(" %lf ", &x);  /* Your original format */
    result = scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("%d %lf\n", result, x);
    fflush(stdout);  // Your system may not need this flush
  } while (result != EOF);
}
```

Comment: Ctrl-D works, my issue now is just fixing and array index. I can take it from here. Thanks a lot for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, after giving up on this first part of the project and debugging the other parts, I have determined that my only issue with the code above is I am trying to reference an index of an array that is out of bounds. I have also determined that the EOF key is ctrl-d, even though I have read and been told by my professor that it is ctrl-z for windows. Regardless, this should be an easy fix. Thanks so much to everyone who provided input!

Comment: There were a lot of exchanges that could have gone on as a `chat`, but you need more than 1 reputation point to do so.  Check help: "What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?".