# Why is scanf stuck inside a while loop?

Tags: c

I used a scanf() inside a while loop.

```
while(1)
{
    int input = 0;
    scanf("%d\n", &input);
    printf("%d\n", input);
}
```

When I run this program, and I enter a number, the `printf()` is not displaying that number unless I enter another number again.  Why?

Comment: Why did you put that `\n` in the `scanf` format string? What was your reason for doing that?

Comment: The problem has arisen before, but I found it hard to find a suitable duplicate.  [Exiting a while loop at EOF using scanf in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220158/exiting-a-while-loop-at-eof-using-scanf-in-c/) has the same basic problem, a format string with both leading and trailing white space around a numeric conversion). I'm moderately sure it is not the only candidate; I'm not sure it is the best candidate.

Answer (score 5):

The `\n` in your `scanf` format is interpreted as "any amount of whitespace".  It keeps reading whitespace (spaces, tabs, or carriage returns) until it hits something that isn't whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You get that behaviour because of the trailing `\n` in the input format.  That looks for white space, and doesn't know when it has finished scanning white space until it comes across a non-white space character.  Don't put trailing white space in your `scanf()`-family format strings unless you really know what you're doing or you aren't actually dealing with user input (the input comes from a program or file or string).

Note that your code should be checking the return value from `scanf()`; it will go into an infinite loop fully if it encounters EOF (or, indeed, if it encounters a non-numeric, non-white space character).  Also, specifying the newline like that does not enforce one number per input line.  The user might merrily type `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` on a single line, and your code will equally merrily cycle 9 times around the loop before getting stuck.

You can also evade the problems by using `fgets()` (or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) to read a line of input and then use `sscanf()` to convert the read data into a number.  Note that the trailing newline is then harmless.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d\n", &input);
```

I usually just go with the follow

```
scanf("%d", &input);
```

without the "\n"

Comment: People who leave the newline off the output are one of the nuisances of programming here on SO. If you want the output to appear in a timely manner, you should output a newline when you've finished with the output.  This is doubly important for diagnostic output; there's no point in diagnostic output that doesn't appear before the program crashes or hangs, and output not finished with a newline may well not appear.  (This answer also has nothing to do with the problem in question.)

Comment: thanks for the comment, I thought scanf with a \n isnt necessary

Comment: btw, I edited the answer, I meant newline is good with an output, but not in an input :D

Comment: Correct.  The original version of your answer only mentioned `printf()`, where the newline in the output is more or less necessary (and left your answer not addressing the problem in the question).  Your modified answer mentioning `scanf()` only is basically on target.  (Incidentally, you can edit comments for up to 5 minutes.)

Comment: I didnt know why I missed it, it's why I shouldn't copy and then past, and should not be lazy and type it all the way :/

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a reference for [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that:

> The format string consists of whitespace characters (any single whitespace character in the format string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from the input)

So the `\n` will trigger this effect, if you don't want this behavior just leave out the `\n`:

```
scanf("%d", &input);
```