# How Terminate scanf() without entring the value?

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"
main()
{
    int option;
    printf("Enter the value :");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    printf("Your value is %d\n",option);
}
```

This is my simple C program to get the value form the user and print it. I have a doubt
why scanf waits till the values is entered, it does not terminate when \n ie., enter key is pressed.

For example :

```
16:26:40-$./a.out
  Enter the value: <-|
<-|
<-|
<-|
<-|
<-|
<-|
   1
Your value is 1
```

I need clear concept and what is the solution for this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try Ctrl-D and Ctrl-Z (EOL and EOF).
Also read answers on [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220158/exiting-a-while-loop-at-eof-using-scanf-in-c)

Comment: Go through this link http://www.mycplus.com/tutorials/c-programming-tutorials/input-output/

Comment: @Ilya I cant understand why it gets \n and not assign it. That was my question

Comment: @Kalanidhi "I cant understand why it gets \n and not assign it." That's because you're using `scanf` not something like `getc` or `gets`. `scanf` is formatted input which only accepts your input when it matches the format specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right.. scanf is not always good.
i would do something like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main( void )
{
    int option;
    int res;
    char buff[20];
    printf("Enter the value :");
    gets(buff);
    res = sscanf(buff,"%d",&option);
    if(res == 1)
        printf("Your value is %d\n",option);
}
```

`gets` terminates at newline and stores the string in `buff`.
sscanf reads like scanf (same format) but from c-string input instead of stdin.

sscanf (and also scanf) returns the number of items in the argument list successfully filled or EOF if it fails to read anything. since we fill only 1 item, we check: `if(res == 1)`.

maybe there some better ways to do this, but i think this is similar to your code, so it may be easier for you to change the code when needed.

Answer (score 2):

### How scanf works:

For each conversion specifier in the format string of `scanf`, it tries to locate an item of the appropriate type in the input, skipping blank space if necessary. It then reads the item and stops when encounters a character that doesn't belongs to the data item.

In case of

```
scanf("%d",&option);
```

`option` is `int` data type. `scanf` searches for the beginning of a number and **ignores white-space characters (newline, space, tab etc.)** and that's why it waits till an integer is entered.

Answer (score 1):

How Ted has mentioned, 'fclose(stdin);' worked well for me too.

At "main" I added:

```
if (signal(SIGINT, handler_SIGINT) == SIG_ERR) {
  printf("Fail capture SIGINT\n");
}
```

sig handler :

```
static void handler_SIGINT(int sig) {
  printf("CTRL+C\n");
  fclose(stdin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you put an fclose(stdin) in the SIGINT handler?
Worked for me, but probably not the best practice:

```
void quitproc(int in)
{
    printf("Got the Ctrl-C\n");
    ExitLoop = 1;

    // This will exit scanf
    fclose(stdin);
}
```