# Ambigious nature of scanf taking input before it is asked to enter from user?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    int num1,num2;
    printf("\n Enter number 1  \t ");  // Ask for input one.   >>>>>>>>    line 1.
    scanf("%d ",&num1);
    printf("\n Entered number is %d \n",num1);

    printf("\n Enter number 2 \t ");   // Ask for input Two. >>>>>>>>>    line 2.
    scanf("%d ",&num2);
    printf("\n Entered number is %d \n",num2);
return;
}
```

I wish to know **REASON**.Please do provide it.

The code above accepts two inputs,first input is asked(By executing line 1) then **user enter one number then terminal *should* ask to enter second input but instead it is taking other number(before executing line2 ) and then asking to enter second input**(i.e after executing line 2).

In the End is is **displaying the two input that are taken *before* executing line two** but *after* executing line 1.

I am confused.I am interested to know reason.
I am using **GCC 4.8.2 on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine.**

Comment: it is working perfectly..http://ideone.com/Xy9d3A

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (you should test its result) and of [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) (you may need to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) at appropriate places)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does reading from stdin flush stdout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123528/does-reading-from-stdin-flush-stdout)

Answer (score 3):

Remove spaces between the scanf of access specifier.

```
scanf("%d ",&num1);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&num1);
```

Because the scanf get the another value due to that spaces.

And kept in the buffer. After the memory has got it get assigned.

It is for all scanf function.

if I input like

```
Enter Number1     1
2

Entered number is 1

Enter number2     3

Entered number is 2.
```

Comment: Sir,Can i know reason? Thanks,Its working after removing spaces.

Comment: @adambure21,Read this link of haccks suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069718/how-terminate-scanf-without-entring-the-value

Answer (score 2):

- It is better to use `int main()` and in the end write `return 0;`
- use `fflush(stdout);` to flush your buffer.

After editing here is the final code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num1,num2;
    printf("\n Enter number 1  \t ");  // Ask for input one.   >>>>>>>>    line 1.
    scanf("%d ",&num1);
    printf("\n Entered number is %d \n",num1);

    printf("\n Enter number 2 \t ");   // Ask for input Two. >>>>>>>>>    line 2.
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d ",&num2);
    printf("\n Entered number is %d \n",num2);
return 0;
}
```

Here is the [Demo.](http://ideone.com/Xy9d3A)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put

```
 fflush(stdout);
```

before the `scanf`

This will flush your buffer

(also a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`)

Comment: Sir,I wish to know reason.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle - Or stuff is just in memory before being flushed. Or read the manual page for scanf as to the value of the return

Comment: No, If this is the reason then the order of output wouldn't change.

Answer (score 1):

You have given a space in scanf for %d. If you remove that space after %d the program will run

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this apart slowly

```
#include <stdio.h>
// void main(){
int main(void) {
    int num1, num2;
    printf("\n Enter number 1  \t "); 
    scanf("%d ",&num1);
    printf("\n Entered number is %d \n",num1);
...
```

1. Use a proper function signature for `main()` - but that is not the main issue.
2. Code prints "\n Enter number 1  \t "
3. `"%d"` directs `scanf()` to scan for text convertible to an `int` in 3 steps:
   A: Scan for optional leading white-space like `'\n'`, `'\t'`, `' '`.  Throw them away.
   B: Scan for text representing an integer like "+1234567890".  If any digits found, save the converted result to the address `&num1`.
   C: Scanning continues in step B until a `char` that does not belong to the `int` is found.  That `char` is "un-read" and returned to `stdin`.
4. (This is where you get in trouble as suggested by @Chandru) `" "` directs `scanf()` to scan for any number (0 or more) white spaces including `'\n'`, `'\t'`, `' '` and others.  Then they are thrown away - not saved.
   B: Scanning *continues*!! until a non-white-space is found. That `char` is "un-read" and returned to `stdin`.
5. Lastly `scanf()` return the value of `1` as that is how many field specifiers were converted.  Code sadly did not check this value.

Recall `stdin` is usually line buffered, which means input is not available to user IO until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit.

User enters <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and `scanf()` scans the "123" and saves `123` to `&num1`.  Then it scans "\n" as that is a white-space in step 4. **and it continues waiting for more white-space**.

User enters <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the first `scanf()` which is not yet done, scans `'4'`, sees it is not a white space and puts `'4'` back in `stdin`. `scanf()` finally returns after 2 lines are entered.  At this point "456\n" are waiting in `stdio` for subsequent `scanf()`.

The second `scanf()` then perpetuates the issue.

Recommend use `fgets()` only for all user input, at least until your are very skilled in C.

```
printf("\n Enter number 1  \t "); 
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &num1) != 1) Handle_BadInput();
else printf("\n Entered number is %d \n",num1);
```