# How would I use EOF to end input in the following code?

Tags: c, scanf, eof

I am currently working on a computer science project and I am stuck whilst trying to work on the final steps. It is very messy thus far, but the code basically takes the first two values given as x and y coordinates, and uses these to produce a total distance. It also then uses a third point to calculate the total uphill and downhill gradients. I have gotten these parts working correctly, however the assignment states: You should read data using scanf until EOF occurs, which can be detected by checking the return value of scanf.
I am wondering how I would go about achieving this? At the moment I have the constraints of my do-while loop being that once it = EOF it will terminate, however this causes the code to terminate at any -1 present. 
Here is the code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double a;
    double total;
    double up;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    double down;
    double zc;
    double yes;
    double m;
    double n;
    double m2;
    double n2;
    double o;
    double p;
    double q;
    double xc;
    double yc;
    int i = 1;
    xc = 1000;
    yc = 1000;
    total = 0;
    down = 0;
    scanf("%lf", &c);
    do 
    {
        if (i == 1) {
            a = c;
            scanf ("%lf", &c);
            i += 1;
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            b = c;
            scanf ("%lf", &c);
            i += 1;
        }

        else if (i ==3) {
            d = c;
            if (xc == 1000 && yc == 1000) {
                i = 4;
            }
            else if (xc != 1000) {
                i = 5;
            }
        }


        else if (i == 4) {
                if (d > zc) {
                    yes = d - zc;
                    up = yes/p;
                    if (up > total) {
                        total = up;
                    }
            }
                if (d < zc) {
                    yes = d - zc;
                    up = yes/p;
                     if (up < 0) {
                        up = up *-1;
                    }
                    if (up > down) {
                        down = up;

            }
        }
            xc = b;
            yc = a;
            zc = d;
            scanf ("%lf", &c);
            i = 1;
        }

        else if (i == 5) {
            m = (xc - b);
            n = (yc - a);
            m2 = m*m;
            n2 = n*n;
            o = m2 + n2;
            p = sqrt(o);
            q = q + p;
            i = 4;
        }
    }

    while (c != EOF && i <= 5);


    printf ("Total distance: %.1lf\n", q);
    printf ("Maximum uphill gradient: %.3lf\n", total);
    printf ("Maximum downhill gradient: %.3lf\n", down);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And given the following input:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 3.0 1.0
1.0 3.0 2.0
1.0 5.0 -1.0
4.0 5.0 -1.0
```

Should return:

```
Total distance: 9.0
Maximum uphill gradient: 1.000
Maximum downhill gradient: 1.500
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. If it is `0`, break.

Comment: `EOF` is not the scanned value, but a possible return value of `scanf`: It returns the number of arguments successfully converted or `EOF` when the input stream runs out. Look at the "Related" answers to the right to learn how to control loops with `scanf`.

Comment: Are you using ctrl-z for EOF? Did you try ctrl-D? You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220158/exiting-a-while-loop-at-eof-using-scanf-in-c

Comment: @MOehm in general, `EOF` should not be tested against the return value of `scanf`, because the test will fail if reading failed due to a different error

Comment: double values must contain a '.' otherwise they must be converted.  Suggest when setting a double variable to some literal that the literal contain a '.'

Comment: when the code wants the user to input something, the code should always output a prompt to let the user know what to enter and perhaps the limits of the value.   Never trust the input from the user, always validate it, including checking the returned value from the scanf() function to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I don't say that you should test against `EOF`, do I? The OP checks for `EOF` in the scanned value, `c`, when you have to look for an `EOF` returned from `scanf`. How to handle the case of unsuccessful or partial scans is another question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the function `scanf()`'s return value. For example:
`scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);` .

1. If read `a` and `b` successfully, it will return `2`.
2. If only read `a` successfully, it will return `1`.
3. If read 'a' failed,now b is irrelative, for example: a not an `int`, it will return `0`.
4. If get the end of the file while `scanf()`, it will return `EOF`.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Minor notes: With "3. If read 'a' and 'b' failed, it will return 0.", `b` success/failure is irrelevant.  Last point is more like "If read error or get the end of the file and scanning `a` was not successful, it will return EOF."

Comment: @chux, maybe I did not say clearly. I will correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the return value of scanf like this `check=scanf("%lf", &c);`
And `while(check != EOF && i <= 5);`
The type of `check` variable must be int.