# Scanf scanning Control + Z

Tags: c

Hello so i have an exercise which i already finished but there is one problem when i need to click control + Z (those keys) i should get value of scanf=-1 and type FINISH but for some reason i need to click  control + Z 3 times for it to work.
does anyone has an idea why it does that?
and for some reason even when i enter it 3 times there is an error about variable h not being used . Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1415
#define G 9.81

float height(float vy, float t);
float horizontal(float vx, float t);
int main()
{
    float h, s, v, vx, vy, t;
    int res, a;
    printf("Enter velocity and angle:- ");
    res = scanf("%f %d",&v,&a);
    if (res != -1)
    {
        vx = v*cos((a*PI) / 180);
        vy = v*sin((a*PI) / 180);
        t = 0.1;
        do
        {
            h = height(vy, t);
            s = horizontal(vx, t);
            printf("time = %.2f .... s=%.2f h=%.2f\n", t, s, h);
            t += 0.1;
        } while (h > 0);
    }
    if (res == -1) printf("FINISH");
    if (h<0) printf("\nFALLEN");

    return 0;


}
float height(float vy, float t)
{
    float h;

    h = vy*t - G*t*t*0.5;

    return h;

}
float horizontal(float vx, float t)
{
    float s;
    s = vx*t;

    return s;


}
```

Comment: Well, `Ctrl+Z` is SIGSTOP. I tried your code, I don't have to press `Ctrl+Z` three times. The program is stopped on the first attempt, however, it is not printing FINISH at the end. If you want such behavior you need to write a signal handler.
What is your platform?

Comment: @GauravPathak On Windows, Ctrl-z is the EOF character, like Ctrl-d on Unix.

Comment: `res = scanf("%f %d",&v,&a);` it contains three directives. First `%f`, second whitespace and third `%d`. May be this is the reason you need to press `Ctrl+Z` three times. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220158/exiting-a-while-loop-at-eof-using-scanf-in-c)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: @GauravPathak: You don't need a space between two numeric conversion specifications in a `scanf()` format (though it does no harm) — the numeric conversions all skip leading white space anyway.  The only conversion specifications that don't skip white space are `%c`, `%[…]` scan sets, and `%n`.

Comment: Typing Control-Z three times is a run-time issue; `h` being used when it isn't initialized is a compile-time diagnostic from a scrupulous compiler.  You should set `float h = 0.0;` so that even if you don't do into the loop because you got `EOF` (usually mapped to `-1`, but don't make that assumption) from `scanf()`.  Note that you should check `if (res != 2)` as the input failed unless you read 2 values successfully.  As to the triple Control-Z, I don't have a good answer.  If you only needed two, I'd have be an explanation, but not for needing three.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hi, i changed the h like you said and now it works but i still have to type it 3 times in order to type FINISH .and if i did if (res != 2) and res were 2 it wont work as it skips the function .

Comment: @GauravPathak but should not %f and %d ignore white spaces  ?